# Angular 12: " NgModule.schemas must be an array.Value could not be determined statically."

Tags: angular, angular12

ERROR Message 

'app-CommodityList' is not a known element:

1. If 'app-CommodityList' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-CommodityList' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

   When i add CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA it doesn't fix the error and add a new one it shows:
   NgModule.schemas must be an array
   Value could not be determined statically.

   **app.module.ts**

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CommodityListComponent } from './CommodityList/CommodityList/CommodityList.component';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CommodityListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas:[ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-CommodityList></app-CommodityList>
```

**CommodityList.html**

```
<p>
  CommodityList works!
</p>
```

**CommodityList.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-CommodityList',
  templateUrl: './CommodityList.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./CommodityList.component.scss']
})
export class CommodityListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Angular Version i'm using is 12.0.1

Comment: Can you share the `CommodityListComponent` ?

Comment: i made no changes in that, i just created it and wanted to see if its working

Comment: try using this selector: `<app-commodity-list></app-commodity-list>` all lowercase dash separated.

Comment: thanks robert issue is resolved... i was using routing and the selector i should be using `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Comment: Great, if you use this component from routing only then you can also remove the `selector:` entirely.